Translating number-theoretic properties into discrete function analysis and developing asymptotic for Sum of Divisors
I would like to share some results that I obtained during my research and to see where this idea might be developed further, as well as gauge how interesting it might be for the community. My work revolves around the relationship between sums of divisors of odd numbers and a function I call $CNR(n)$.
Definition of $CNR(n)$
The function $CNR(n)$ counts the number of solutions to the equation $n = x^2 - (x - k)^2$, which is equivalent to $n = q(2x - k)$, where $k, q \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n$ is an odd number. Here, $q$ is a divisor of $n$, which links $CNR(n)$ to the divisor function $\sigma_0(n)$.
The full formula for $CNR(n)$ is:
$$
\text{CNR}(n) = \sum_{k=2}^{\left\lceil \frac{\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor}{2} \right\rceil}  \left\lceil \frac{n - (2k - 1)^2}{4k - 2} \right\rceil = \sum_{k=2}^{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor} \left\lceil \frac{\sigma_0(2k - 1) - 2}{2} \right\rceil
$$
Asymptotic Formula for $CNR(n)$
To derive the asymptotics of $CNR(n)$, I removed the ceiling function $\lceil \cdot \rceil$ in the original sum, obtaining a lower bound for $CNR(n)$:
$$
\sum_{k=2}^{R} \frac{n - (2k - 1)^2}{4k - 2}
$$
where $R = \left\lceil \frac{\left\lfloor \sqrt{n} \right\rfloor}{2} \right\rceil$. This provides a good lower bound, and the next step is to estimate the contribution of the fractional parts caused by removing the ceiling function. The contribution of these fractional parts is approximately $(R-1) \cdot C$, where $C$ tends to $1/2$ as $n$ increases.
Thus, the asymptotic approximation for $CNR(n)$ is:
$$
\text{CNR}(n) \approx \frac{1}{4} \left( 2 - 2 R^2 + n H_{R - \frac{1}{2}} + n \left(2\ln{2} - 2 \right) \right) + C(R-1)
$$
where $H_x$ is the harmonic number, and the constant $C$ tends to $1/2$ as $n$ increases.
Connection to the sum of divisors of odd numbers
An interesting result arises from the connection between $CNR(n)$ and the sum of divisors of odd numbers, expressed by the following identity:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sigma_0(2k-1) = 2 \left(\text{CNR}(2n) + n\right) - \left\lceil \frac{\lfloor \sqrt{2n} \rfloor}{2} \right\rceil
$$
Asymptotic Formula for the Sum of Divisors
Using the asymptotic formula for $CNR(n)$, we can derive the asymptotic expression for the sum of divisors of odd numbers. Substituting the asymptotic approximation of $CNR(2n)$ into the identity above, we get:
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \sigma_0(2k-1) = n H_{R - \frac{1}{2}} + 2n \ln 2 - R^2 + o(n),
$$
where $R = \left\lceil \frac{\lfloor \sqrt{2n} \rfloor}{2} \right\rceil$, and $H_{R - \frac{1}{2}}$ is the harmonic number.
For example, when $n = 10^{13}$, the absolute error for that asymptotic formula is approximately 1380.
Questions:

How useful could this method be for analyzing functions similar to $CNR(n)$? If anyone has come across similar research, I would appreciate references, as I was unable to find information on this approach (only substantive reference I could find).
How interesting this idea in the field of analytic number theory?

I would greatly appreciate your thoughts, suggestions, and criticism!

You say sum of divisors, but do you mean number of divisors?

@GregMartin The sum of divisors function is more generally defined as $$\sigma_z(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n} d^z$$ so you're correct that $$\sigma_0(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n} 1.$$.

OEIS entry A099774 gives the asymptotic $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \sigma_0(2 k-1) \approx \frac{1}{2} (n \log(n)+(2 \gamma-1+3 \log(2)), n)$$ where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant.

@StevenClark Yes, you're right.
My point is that it is interesting that we interpret the solution of some Diophantine equation in terms of discrete functions and from them we obtain asymptotics which behaves the same way as the proposed formula.
In fact, my asymptotics gives exact values for some n (which is quite unusual): 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 12, 15.
Numerical analysis does not give specific results, the asymptotics are very close to each other, sometimes my asymptotics are better, sometimes the one you suggested is better.

$${(a,b)\in\mathbb{N}^2:a^2-b^2=n}=\left{\left(\frac{n/d+d}{2},\frac{n/d-d}{2}\right)\in\mathbb{N}^2:d\mid n\right}\=\left{\left(\frac{n/d+d}{2},\frac{n/d-d}{2}\right):[d\mid n]\land [d<\sqrt{n}]\land [d\equiv n/d\text{ mod }2]\right}$$

Given arbitrary $f,g,h:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{C}$ and any $m\in\mathbb{N}$ let $\{\chi_{m,t}:1\leq t\leq m\land \gcd(m,t)=1\}$ be the $\phi(m)$ dirichlet characters modulo $m$ in any given order, now with these definition we can prove:
$$\text{(1)}:\sum_{\substack{a^2-b^2=n\\ (a,b)\in\mathbb{N}^2}}f(a)g(b)=\sum_{\substack{d\mid n\\d<\sqrt{n}}}f\left(\frac{n/d+d}{2}\right)g\left(\frac{n/d-d}{2}\right)\chi_{2,1}(n/d-d+1)$$
$$\text{(2)}:\sum_{\substack{d\mid n\\d\equiv r\bmod m}}f(d)g(n/d)=\frac{1}{\varphi(m)}\sum_{\substack{1\leq t\leq m\\\gcd(t,m)=1}}\chi_{m,t}(r)^{-1}\left(\sum_{d\mid n}f(d)g(n/d)\chi_{m,t}(d)\right)$$
$$\text{(3)}:\sum_{n\leq x}\left(\sum_{d\mid n}f(d)g(n/d)\right)h(n)=\sum_{n\leq x}f(n)\sum_{k\leq x/n}g(k)h(kn)=\sum_{n\leq x}g(n)\sum_{k\leq x/n}f(k)h(kn)\\=\sum_{n\leq y}f(n)\sum_{k\leq x/n}g(k)h(kn)+\sum_{n\leq x/y}g(n)\sum_{k\leq x/n}f(k)h(kn)-\sum_{n\leq x/y}g(n)\sum_{k\leq y}f(k)h(kn)$$
For arbitrary $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and any integer $r$ thus using these identities we can derive not just your results but a faster version when $y=\sqrt{x}$ (this is called the Dirichlet hyperbola method) for the sum $\sum_{n\leq x}d(n)\chi_{2,1}(n)$. In fact you can do all this with just an undergraduate education while professional mathematicians are able to go much further using more advanced Fourier analysis to estimate $\sum_{n\leq x}d(n)\chi_{m,r}(n)$ as can be found: here.... With all that said I would answer question one by "not very useful unfortunately" and question two would be answered as follows "these ideas are interesting, but require more tools to study in depth".
